# Greasemonkey: (Cross-Site) Load another page with javascript executed

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey for `http://foo.com/index.html`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        foo helper
// @description Append data fetched from bar.com
// @include     http://*foo.com/index.html
var bar = cross_site_get_page("http://bar.com");
document.body.appendChild(var);
```

However, on `bar.com`, everything is generated by javascript.

`bar.com/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body> trivial information
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get `bar.com/index.html` after the js code has been executed?

P.S. previous solution:
1. `createElement("iframe")` can't handle cross site policy
2. `GM_xmlhttpRequest` js code won't be executed

Comment: You need add `bar.com` to your `@include`. Inject your script to the `<iframe>`. And use `postMessage` to send result back to your scripts run on `foo.com`. Another idea is use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to access backend of `foo.com` without loading its web page.

Comment: `postMessage` between `bar.com` and `foo.com` will not work because of the same-origin policy and `GM_xmlhttpRequest` wont execute Javascript. You could use `GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue` instead, they work across sites.